# having trouble installing vim/macvim properly

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm trying to systematically [download from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012203/gvim-or-macvim-in-mac-os-x), but I keep getting an error that seems unclear to me. Could anyone help me understand what is going on and what can I do to fix this? Here's what the error looks like:

```
Last 15 lines from /Users/xxxxx/Library/Logs/Homebrew/macvim/01.configure:
--enable-rubyinterp
--enable-tclinterp
--with-tlib=ncurses
--with-compiledby=Homebrew
--with-local-dir=/usr/local
--enable-cscope
--enable-pythoninterp

configure: creating cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/tmp/macvim20160405-2972-uihf5e/macvim-snapshot-100/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Can't you just download and install MacVim? It's a two minutes affair.

Comment: "checking whether the C compiler works... no": See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844522/os-x-10-9-2-checking-whether-the-c-compiler-works-no) helps.