# Mac OS Sierra: checking whether the C compiler works... no

Tags: c, xcode, macos, gcc, macos-sierra

I want to compile a C library on my MacOS Sierra system, but I am getting the following error:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/local/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/local/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/macuser/Downloads/libr':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I tried setting the symlink as suggested in [OS X 10.9.2: checking whether the C compiler works... no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844522/os-x-10-9-2-checking-whether-the-c-compiler-works-no) :

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeD‌​efault.xctoolchain/ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.‌​11.xctoolchain
```

I tried setting the CC path and install xcode as in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216573/cant-compile-source-code-on-mac :

```
export CC=clang
xcode-select --install
```

and accept the license. But nothing worked. Are there any new steps to consider on Sierra to get the command line tools running properly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Start Xcode, select 'Preferences', then 'Locations'. You'll notice a dropdown control at 'Command Line Tools'. Select the newest version, close the dialog window, then call brew again. Restart your computer and run it again.

Comment: I'm using SSH to connect to a Macos, how can I do what you said through the command line ?

Comment: Very late but got the command. `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`