# Error in R package "igraph" installation

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to install R package "igraph" in Linux server and stuck with some errors.

I've tried `install.packages("igraph")`, and got these error messages :

1. Problem related with `checking whether the C compiler works... no` :

   ```
   * installing *source* package ‘igraph’ ...
   ** package ‘igraph’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   checking for gcc... /usr/local/bin/gcc
   checking whether the C compiler works... no
   configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpPaaksz/R.INSTALL8c157a39a973/igraph':
   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
   See `config.log' for more details
   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘igraph’
   ```
2. Problem related with `lazyeval.c:53: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode` :

   ```
   lazyeval.c: In function ‘make_lazy_dots’:
   lazyeval.c:53: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
   lazyeval.c:53: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
   lazyeval.c:63: error: redefinition of ‘nxt’
   lazyeval.c:53: note: previous definition of ‘nxt’ was here
   make: *** [lazyeval.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘igraph’
   ```

My environment is

- Linux
- R 3.4.3

Would anyone give me a piece of precious advice?

I close this post due to consistency of my question, though I still can't install the package. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you find the `config.log` and upload that?

Comment: What OS are you running exactly? How did you install R? Have you run something like `apt-get build-essential`? That should include a compiler.

Comment: Possibly Relevant [os-x-10-9-2-checking-whether-the-c-compiler-works-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844522/os-x-10-9-2-checking-whether-the-c-compiler-works-no)

Comment: @SeGa Trying to find it, 
@MrFlick I added my information on the post. ``apt-get build-essential`` gives me this ``-bash: apt-get: command not found``.

Comment: Thanks, @G5W. I was struggling little bit, and tried to change my ~/.R/Makevars file, which solves ``checking whether the C compiler works``. However, new error I updated comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handled two problems by changing my ~/.R/Makevars file as

```
C=gcc-5
CXX=g++
CXX1X = g++-5
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic
```

First three lines are for the problem 1, and the last one for 2.

Comment: I am just curios.  How did you figure this out from a log ?

Comment: @akh22 Thanks for your interest on this, but it has been more than a year since I posted, so I can't remember it now.